# Is it halal to post videos/images with moderately dressed non-muslim women on it for marketing purposes?

Tags: halal-haram, women, non-muslim

I am a freelance marketer. For my clients(businesses), I have to create & edit **images & videos** then post those on the company's social media. And often these media contain **non-muslim non-hijabi women**. Albeit they're there for marketing purposes, they are decently dressed(not in a sexually provocative manner) but still showing hair, neck & stuff. In case of videos, they talk about the product. Products being promoted are halal.

So, is what I am doing Halal? If it's not then is my income from it haram too?

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly Haram to use women pics for marketing especially if they are not in full hijab clothes style , im working in this field " Marketing" also ,for me I used to except all clients who need to use this in their marketing campaigns.
And remember hadith of our Prophet (ﷺ) said,

> " Whoever leaves something for Allah, Allah will substitute for him
> something much better."

Finally as a marketer you knows that marketing is not putting your self in one way , you could be more creative by thinking out of the box and getting new idea that give your clients what they needs from the campaigns without have more sins.
Allah bless you my brother. people uses women in marketing because actually its sexual impressions sells in a good way , try to find something creative to sell more and believe me big proportion of them will agree as you did their target.

Comment: You have not provided any source to support the claim that it isn't allowed to use images of women in marketing. This is just your opinion until you do.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I'll take it into consideration Inshallah